# Form layout is not visible in visual C# for Smart Device->Windows CE 5.0->Device Application project

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, embedded

I am developing an application for windows CE 6.0.

When i start a windows CE 5.0 device application project, IDE shows me the form in the solution explorer but there is no form layout in the designer. Instead, it appears as a control similar to openFileDialog control.
[alt text http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/7130/formdesignererrorpictur.jpg](http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/7130/formdesignererrorpictur.jpg)

The same problems does not occur if i try it on a windows application project.
Did i miss installing any required API libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I form layout is degraded because of conflicting APIs.** 
Because multiple versions of the same library can be the cause of such a problem.
I had installed .net compact framework 1, 2 , 3 and 3.5 SP1.
I uninstalled all and then when Visual Studio asked to install .net compact framework 2. 
I got the appropriate layout back.